# Em que sentido é feita a derivação regressivo entre afecto e afectar?

Tags: morfologia, conversão

Não consigo perceber pelas entradas no dicionário se [afecto](https://dicionario.priberam.org/afecto) é derivação regressiva de [afectar](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/afectar) ou vice-versa. Portanto em que sentido é feita a derivação (ou *conversão* como lhe chamam alguns autores)? Se não há uma relação de derivação/conversão entre afecto e afectar por que é?

Dois exemplos habituais de derivação regressiva são:

- Muro (nome) -> murar (verbo)
- Colher (verbo) -> colha (nome)

Mas no caso de afecto/afectar não é claro.

Comment: Deixa outro tentar. Só quero dizer que a etimologia é muito relevante  pois é a única maneira para saber se um vocábulo é regressivo OU não. No seu caso, a origem são duas palavras latins diferentes. Um não vem do outro. Um vem de um verbo e o outro de um ajetivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando fontes históricas ou análises formais não revelam claramente qual palavra surgiu primeiro, parece ser comum se recorrer ao critério de Barreto (1982): se o significado é de ação, então o verbo é primitivo e o substantivo derivado, caso contrário, o substantivo é o primitivo (e.g., "azeitar" derivaria de "azeite", e "abano" de "abanar"). Talvez esse critério tenha sua utilidade, mas obviamente não esclarece a etimologia das palavras. Como Valter Kehdi (1998) [coloca](https://doi.org/10.11606/issn.2176-9419.v0i2p205-213):

> O critério propos­to por Mario Barreto (e tao divulgado por nossas gramáticas posterio­res), de que o substantivo, quando exprime ação  (como *luta*), é deriva­do, ao passo que, quando expressa uma noção concreta (como *disco*), é primitivo<sup>[Barreto, 1982]</sup>, não se revela pertinente do ponto de  vista sincrônico, pois está baseado exclusivamente no valor semântico do verbo. Ora, este não só exprime ação (com diferentes matizes), como também sen­timento, estado, fenômenos atmosféricos, etc.; trata-se, portanto, de um critério excessivamente genérico, 0 que lhe rouba o caráter operatório. Acresce que, com frequência, em função  do uso, esses deverbais adquirem significado concreto (p.ex., caça indica também o resultado da  ação): muitas vezes, o significado dinâmico é praticamente desco­nhecido hoje em dia (*agasalho* (s.), entre outros exemplos).

Se, ainda assim, quiséssemos aplicar esse critério ao par "afetar/afeto", enfrentaríamos a dificuldade que "afetar" expressa ação, mas "afeto" tem vários significados concretos.

Contudo, essa parece ser uma dificuldade com que não temos que lidar. Seguindo a indicação de Lambie, e até onde pude identificar, as origens etimológicas das duas palavras de fato parecem ser diferentes e, portanto, não derivariam uma da outra. Como a Infopédia coloca:

> [afetar](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/afetar) — Do latim affectāre, «aspirar a; afectar»
> [afeto](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/afeto) — Do latim affectu-, «afeição; ternura»

Ou, em maior detalhe, o Houaiss:

> ###### afetar (1569 cf. DA)
>
> latim *affēcto*,*as*,*āvi*,*ātum*,*āre* no sentido de 'pôr-se a' depois 'tentar obter, buscar', verbo freqüentativo de *afficĭo*,*is*,*ēci*,*ēctum*,*icĕr* ou *adficĕree* (de *ad-* e *facio*) 'pôr em certa disposição (física ou moral), afetar, trocar, tratar bem ou mal, mover, comover', por sua vez, derivado de *ad* + *facĕre* no sentido de 'fazer'; forma divergente erudita *afeitar*; ver *faz-*; forma histórica 1569 *afetado*, 1619 *affectar*
>
> ###### afeto (sXV cf. IVPM)
>
> substantivo latim *affectus,us* no sentido de 'estado psíquico ou moral (bom ou mau), afeição, disposição de alma, estado físico, sentimento, vontade'; forma divergente erudita *afeito*; ver *faz-*; forma histórica sXV *afecto*, sXV *feito*, sXV *afeyto*, sXV *affecto*
>
> ###### afeto (1611 GuerRel)
>
> adjetivo latim *affēctus,a,um* no sentido de 'afetado, cheio, tomado de, comovido, afetado de vários modos', particípio passado de *adfectāre*, frequentativo de *adficĕre* (*afficĕre*) 'pôr em certa disposição (física ou moral), afetar, trocar'; forma divergente erudita 1 *afeito*; ver *faz-*; forma histórica 1562 *afeyto*, 1611 *affectos*

Onde também se encontra a explicação para a similaridade das palavras, apesar de suas etimologias distintas, como coloca bad_coder (minha ênfase):

> Em GuerRel diz explicitamente *affēctus* ser participio passado de *adfectāre* nas declinações do latim. Portanto **o radical é comum mas exterior à morfologia do português**

Fontes:
 <sub>**Barreto**: M. Barreto (1982) "De gramática e de lingugagem", ed. Presenca, pg. 331, via Voitel Kehd (1998) "A derivação regressiva em português", Filologia E Linguística Portuguesa, 2, 205-213. https://doi.org/10.11606/issn.2176-9419.v0i2p205-213</sub>
 <sub>**DA**: ACADEMIA DAS CIÊNCIAS DE LISBOA. Dicionário da língua portuguesa. [1793]. Reprodução fac-similada assinalando o II centenário da edição. Lisboa, 1993. Tomo primeiro: A [a-azurrar]. [A obra contém citações de documentos históricos anteriores à sua publicação, que foram aproveitadas para datação de verbetes.]</sub>
 <sub>**GuerRel**: GUERREIRO, Fernão. Relaçam annual das cousas que fizeram os padres da Companhia de Jesus, nas partes da India Oriental ... nos annos de 600, 601, 602 e 603, 604 e 605, 606 e 607, 607 e 608. Lisboa, 1602, 1605, 1607, 1609, 1611.</sub>
 <sub>**IVPM**: Índice do vocabulário do português medieval. Rio de Janeiro: Fundação Casa de Rui Barbosa. v. 1. (A), 1986; v. 2 (B-C) 1988; v. 3 (D) 1994; suplemento (A-C) (Confluência Revista do Instituto de Língua Portuguesa e do Liceu Literário Português, n. 3, separata, Rio de Janeiro, 1992). [No fichário (FichIVPM), arquivado na Fundação Casa de Rui Barbosa, estão incluídas cerca de 170.000 fichas datilografadas com a transcrição das passagens que documentam os vocábulos medievais, incluídos naturalmente os que se iniciam pelas letras E, F, G ...V, X, Z].</sub>

Comment: Excellente recolha de referências! Gostei especialmente do comentário de Valter Khedi a enquadrar o problema na sincronia! Em GuerRel diz explicitamente *affēctus* ser participio passado de *adfectāre* nas declinações do latim. Portanto o radical é comum mas exterior à morfologia do português - assim faz sentido.

Comment: Comentário pertinente, @bad_coder — inclusive me permiti adicioná-lo à resposta.